# Error occurred while accessing Java Security Manager Privilege Block when change user password

Tags: wso2

When i try to change passwords for users in carbon on API-M i get "Error occurred while accessing Java Security Manager Privilege Block", but passwords are changed despite on error. Passwords are not change for existing users, for new users passwords are change. Recently i changed certificates on API-M. 
What is the problem? Do certificates affect on this error?

Answer (score 1):

Your debug logs contains only client side exception

org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.stub.UserAdminStub.changePassword(UserAdminStub.java:3678)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.ui.UserAdminClient.changePassword(UserAdminClient.java:102)

In order to get an idea about actual backend exception have a look below places. You may probably remote debug the code based on APIM version you are using.

[1] https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/blob/v4.4.26/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/user/core/ldap/ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java#L682

[2] https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/blob/v4.4.26/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/user/core/common/AbstractUserStoreManager.java#L1108

[3] https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/blob/v4.4.26/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/user/core/common/AbstractUserStoreManager.java#L176

Comment: I didn't find files AbstractUserStoreManager.java and ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java on my API-M. What should i do with them?

Answer (score 0):

"Error occurred while accessing Java Security Manager Privilege Block" is a generic error message comes from user core component. Please provide complete stack trace to investigate the issue. 
You can put below entry

log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.user.core=DEBUG

to log4j.properties to get more information. 
There is no direct relationship with certificates.

Comment: i added debug log